# Why ClassName.class.getFields() returns only public fields?

Tags: java

I have one class A

```
public class A {
    String host = "localhost";
    public String port = "8078";
    protected String preFix = "www.";
    private String postFix = "/uploads";
}
```

I am getting field details of class A using below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = A.class.getFields();
        System.out.println("fields are:" + Arrays.toString(fields));
    }
```

The output is

```
fields are:[public java.lang.String org.test.A.port]
```

I understand getFields() method returns only those fields which are declared with public access specifier.

**But why Java implemented getFields()
like this?**

**What is the main intention of Java Team for this kind of implementation?**

Comment: Are you looking for `getDeclaredFields()`?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Wont it be a security issue if it conveniently returned private and protected fields as well???

Comment: @AbishekManoharan with reflection, you generally have access to everything. The modifiers can be thought of as hints, not as absoultes. Just because something is declared as private does not mean the JVM takes any measure to "protect" this attribute / method.

Comment: @Turing85: the JVM *does* take care. If you ask for non-`public` members, the `SecurityManager` (if one has been installed) will be asked for permission.

Comment: @Holger the security manager will, yes. But not the VM itself. And you said it yourself: *if one has been installed*. :)

Comment: @Turing85: The JVM enforces access restrictions in the first place. It is the special library feature of Reflection which makes access override possible but it checks the `SecurityManager`, if there is one. To make secure environments possible, not mandatory. But that’s the whole point of it. There are two methods, `getFields()` and `getDeclaredFields()` requiring different permissions. In restricted environments, it may make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of `getFields` is to return all public fields available via class, including inherited ones.

If you are looking for list of fields declared in this class use `getDeclaredFields`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods in the `Class` class concerning the fields:

- [`getFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--) returns all the publicly accessible fields of this
  class (interface) **and all of its superclasses**,
- [`getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) returns
  all fields that are **declared on this class** (interface), including fields with 
  public, default, protected and private visibility.

The distinction between those two methods use cases should be quite clear.

Comment: getDeclaredFields can throw a SecurityException if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Davio `getFields()` also may throw `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is `getDeclaredFields` which returns fields regardless of its modifier your question does not make sense. The point was to have methods for all use cases which are common. For example using `getFields` you can iterate over a `static` class having constants only (this was before `enum`s were introduced). So to answer your question this was partly to cover common use cases and now partly legacy.